# read lines from file and split them into two numbers and perform calculations and write them into file c++

Tags: c++, string, file, input

!!!!Strictly no pointers or arrays!!

Example contents in file.

33 + 20

Max of 17 and 53

14 minus -5

4 times 10

44 - 9

4 * 10

8 / 3

33 + 20

8 divided by 3

Min of 67 and 83

i wrote the following code to identify the keywords but i'm unable to retrieve the numbers

"#includeiostream"

"#includefstream"

"#includestring"

using namespace std;

int main() {

```
ifstream op;
int s;
string line;
op.open("t.txt");
string f[10] = { "+", "plus", "-", "minus", "/", "divided", "Min", "Max", "*", "times" };

while (!op.eof()) {

    getline(op, line);
    cout << line << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        s = line.find(f[i]);
        if (s!=-1) {
            if (f[i] == "+" || f[i] == "plus")
                cout << "perform addition" << endl;
            else if (f[i] == "-" || f[i] == "minus")
                cout << "Perform subtraction"<<endl;
            else if (f[i] == "*" || f[i] == "times")
                cout << "Perform multiplication" << endl;
            else if (f[i] == "/" || f[i] == "divided")
                cout << "Perform division" << endl;
            else if (f[i] == "Max")
                cout << "Max" << endl;
            else if (f[i] == "Min")
                cout << "Min" << endl;

        }
    }
}
op.close();
system("pause");
```

}

Comment: !!!!Strictly no pointers or arrays!!

Comment: strings *are* arrays of characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a good start but you still have some work to do.  Your loop will (mostly) find the operations to perform on each line (watch out for that unary minus sign).  Finding the operands for the operations will be a little trickier and, unless you are allowed to use regular expressions, will involve some character manipulation.

The basic idea will go something like this.  Start at the beginning of the line and search until you find the first digit.  This can be done any number of ways including using library functions like isdigit to a more brute force method like :

if (line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9')

Once you're on a digit, continue to accumulate characters until you no longer find a digit.  The digits you found can be converted to actual numbers in a variety of ways.  You can use a library function like atoi, you can use the stringstream class, you could use scanf, or you could build the number yourself by multiplying the previous number by 10 and adding the current digit :

```
int sum = 0;
while (isdigit(line[i]))
{
    sum = sum * 10 + line[i] - '0';
    i++;
}
```

Once you stop finding digits, continue looking at characters in the line until a second digit is found.  Repeat the process (above) to create your second operand.  As mentioned before, you will want to handle cases where the unary minus shows up.  At this point you should have your two operands and your operator and you can perform the expression and output the result.

Comment: `strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base)` can do the conversion for you, and give you a pointer to the first character after the number.  It's much better to use the `strtol` library function than writing your own, since it will be bulletproof.  I think you already have a bug in your loop: it should be  `sum = ... - '0'`, not `'a'`.  Using `isdigit` when scanning for the start of a number will cover any locale-dependent corner-cases.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ahh, you're right, of course.  Fingers on autopilot.  I've made the change.